# Issue in loading a portlet in portal

Tags: apache-flex, portlet, liferay, portal

I have my Flex application loaded in a Liferay portal.  I have an issue when I maximize or minimize the portlet window that contains the flex application. Each time the application gets loaded when I maximize or minimize the application.So the user views the homepage of the application and not the page where they were working when they maximize or minimize the portlet window.I noticed that current state isn't maintained only in case of Flex application. The state gets maintained in application that has JSF/JSP as UI.If there is a solution available either from Flex or Liferay, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Hm, haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but with the portlet lifecycle, when you resize the portlet is getting a "VIEW" event or doView call, and the entire page is being reloaded. You would have to have some method of retaining state on the server side so when the view is reloaded and your Flex app reloaded, it could go to the correct place in your Flex app.

YMMV

Comment: Thank you for the response. I achieved it using the SharedObject in Flex. Will post the reply after completing the testing.

Comment: Great to hear! Look forward to hearing more about this, as I have teammates who are itching to add Flex to there portal mix.